# how do i set cookie for a different domain?

Tags: javascript, java, cookies

I am running springboot and I have tried to set a cookie and redirect a page

```
origin: http://abc.example.com  (generate a cookie)
destination: http://xyz.example.com (set the cookie for login)

@RequestMapping(value = "/getUrl",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Object getRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response) {
    String auth = generateKey();
    addCookie("auth", auth, response, -1);
    ResponseCode resp = new ResponseCode();
    resp.setUrl("http://xyz.example.com");

    return CommonUtil.toJson(resp);
}

public void addCookie(String name,
                      String value,
                      HttpServletResponse response, int exp) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
    cookie.setMaxAge(exp);
    cookie.setPath("/");

    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

and HTML
once I get the request I would just redirect using

```
window.location.href=url;
```

But in `xyz.example.com` I dont see the cookie is being set.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a domain, it will only apply to the specific subdomain it was set on.

> Domain specifies allowed hosts to receive the cookie. If unspecified, it defaults to the host of the current document location, excluding subdomains. If Domain is specified, then subdomains are always included.
>
> For example, if Domain=mozilla.org is set, then cookies are included on subdomains like developer.mozilla.org.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

So you probably need to specify a domain of 'example.com' to have it readable on both subdomains.

Comment: I have tried to set cookie.setDomain(".example.com") but it didnt work